# Use MSVAD faild

Tags: windows, driver

I builed [Msvad](https://github.com/uri247/wdk81/tree/master/Microsoft%20Virtual%20Audio%20Device%20Driver%20Sample/C%2B%2B)(micarray) and install it in windows 10. But i have a error code 48 "**The driver for this device has been blocked from starting because it is known to have problems with Windows. Contact the hardware vendor for a new driver. (Code 48)**".I built with vs2019, configuration is **win8.1 debug**, target os version is **win10 or higher**, file inf is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/et-ee/windows-hardware/drivers/audio/modified-inf-for-msvad-micarray),i created catalog file with [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/inf2cat),I turned on testsigning. Please help me. Thanks you so much.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found answer in [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2d5211d1-1658-4b9f-b29f-a0a505019921/help-with-tutorial-code-in-msvad?forum=wdk). Just added the file , msvad.inf to the package project - kept as target Windows 8.1. Build all and install "devcon install msvad.inf *MSVADMicArray"